# expectation of stopping time in Wiener process

Tags: stochastic-processes, expectation, stopping-times

Let $(W_t)$ be a Wiener process and for $a>0$ define stopping time:
$$\tau = \inf \left\{t>0: W_t + at = 5\right\}$$

a) show $\tau < \infty$ a.s;

b) compute $\mathbb{E}\tau$.

I have done the first part and in the second part I'm trying to show that $\mathbb{E}\tau < \infty$, because then $\mathbb{E}W_t = 0 \implies \mathbb{E}\tau = \frac{5}{a}$. I think I should use $W_t^2 - t$ matringale, but I cannot use it in the right way.

Edit. Ok, I've managed to do it.

Comment: How did you prove (a)?

Comment: By the law of the iterated logarithm.

Comment: You mean, assuming that $a>0$?

Comment: Yes, of course, I forgot to add this, sorry. I'll fix it.